# Starting motion manager with startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue does not produce magnetometer readings

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I started a motion manager to queue (instead of the usually polling method.)

```
[self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:self.motionQueue
                                                withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
                                                    [self.data addObject:motion]; // Record the data.
                                                }];
```

And a sample output from my NSMutableArray, self.data, is:

```
"QuaternionX 0.276414 QuaternionY -0.011645 QuaternionZ -0.004033 QuaternionW 0.960960 
UserAccelX -0.006354 UserAccelY -0.021349 UserAccelZ 0.040370 
RotationRateX -0.277591 RotationRateY -0.080331 RotationRateZ -0.011461 
MagneticFieldX 0.000000 MagneticFieldY 0.000000 MagneticFieldZ 0.000000 MagneticFieldAccuracy -1 @ 200988.637128"
```

Notice that all the readings for magneticFeld are zeros. Also, its accuracy is -1.

I do not have this problem when I started the motionManager the usual way - i.e. by calling

```
[self.motionManager startDeviceUpdatesUsingReferenceFrames:f];
```

Is there something else I need to do to get the magnetometer to work when receiving updates in a separate queue?

Comment: -1 mean uncalibrated. The magnetometer _always_ starts out uncalibrated. If you wait a while doesn't it start working?

Comment: Oh, and the motion manager's `showsDeviceMovementDisplay` needs to be YES so that the calibration interface can appear, _and_ it is important that Compass Calibration be turned on the user's Settings (Privacy > Location Services > System Services). I once turned that off and couldn't figure out why the magnetometer stopped working... :)

Comment: Hi matt, I've waiting a long time and it didn't happen. Even went to the compass app and got it calibrated there. But the readings are still the same.

Comment: Hmm. There is a separate `startMagnetometerUpdatesToQueue:withHandler:`. Maybe the magnetic readings are only reported there.

Comment: Here's another idea: What was your motion manager's reference frame before you started the updates? Some reference frames don't use the magnetometer so maybe it just never comes on.

Comment: Hi matt, my reference frame is CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitaryCorrectedZVertical. It should come in because apparently the magnetometer is used to correct drift here, which is why I'm concerned.

Comment: Agreed. Does the `startMagnetometerUpdates` idea work?